# smooth scrolling get stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used a jquery script to get my page smooth scrolled between anchors and set "active" to the menu.

The scrolling is stuck and not scrolled smoothly.

Did anyone else now about this issue?

my page is: http://miriwein.com/

my script for smooth scroll:

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
topMenu = $(".anc"),
topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()-150,
 // All list items
 menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
 // Anchors corresponding to menu items
 scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
    var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
    if (item.length) { return item; }
 });

 // Bind click handler to menu items
 // so we can get a fancy scroll animation
 menuItems.click(function(e){
    var href = $(this).attr("href"),
    offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 2000);
    e.preventDefault();
 });

 // Bind to scroll
 $(window).scroll(function(){
 // Get container scroll position
 var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

 // Get id of current scroll item
 var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
    if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
        return this;
 });
 // Get the id of the current element
 cur = cur[cur.length-1];
 var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

 if (lastId !== id) {
    lastId = id;
 // Set/remove active class
 menuItems
 .parent().removeClass("active")
 .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
}                   
});
```

Comment: In Chrome the scrolling works for me fine (when clicking menu items)...my only comments would be the scrolling is super slow...change the value 2000 to 600 or something much faster.

Comment: @MikeBarwick The scroll does not jumps a bit?

Comment: Negative. Not for me on Chrome, mac.

Comment: @MikeBarwick Thank you! for some reason it jumps for me and for my client. (linux, windows).